# FFMpeg and max bitrate

Tags: ffmpeg, constraints, bitrate

For a personal project, using AV1 codec, I have a bitrate constraint for a video to 88kbps, with choosen video bitrate at 66kbps and mono audio bitrate at 22kbps.

I currently use this command:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c:v libaom-av1 -strict -2 -b:v 66150 -c:a libfdk_aac -ar 22050 -b:a 22050 -ac 1 -maxrate 66150 -bufsize 66150 -vf scale=720:-1 -movflags +faststart output.mp4
```

However, my final video has a **95kbps** bitrate:

> Duration: 00:01:09.73, start: 0.000000, bitrate: **95 kb/s**
>
> Stream #0:0(und): Video: av1 (Main) (av01 / 0x31307661), yuv420p(tv, progressive), 720x302, **69 kb/s**, 24 fps, 24 tbr, 12288 tbn, 12288 tbc (default)
>
> Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 22050 Hz, mono, fltp, **22 kb/s** (default)

Is there a method to validate my need? Is it normal that 66+22>88kbps?

Regards,

**EDIT 1:** as @Gyan suggested, I've tried to reduce -bufsize parameter, but I still have a too high bitrate. The most working way is to set video bitrate -b:v to **50kbps**, but it gives poorer image...

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c:v libaom-av1 -strict -2 -b:v 50k -c:a libfdk_aac -ar 22050 -b:a 22050 -ac 1 -minrate 33075 -maxrate 66150 -bufsize 44100 -vf scale=-1:360 -movflags +faststart -threads 1 output.mp4
```

Any idea to limit overhead, if overhead is in cause?

Comment: The container has its own overhead. You have to account for that. Lower the bufsize to tighten the deviation by the video encoder.

Comment: @Gyan thanks for your tip. I make tests and will Edit my post with the result.

Comment: @AurelienStride Might be a good time to consider using libravie rather than libaom-av1...

Comment: @andrew.46 sure, but I don't find any documentation on it. Can you share a link plz?

Comment: @AurelienStride I have done some work with this here: https://askubuntu.com/q/1189174/57576 while FFmpeg docs have this: https://askubuntu.com/q/1189174/57576

Answer (score 1):

After a few exchanges, here's a very suitable solution, with a **84kbps** bitrate and a good image quality, thanks to this [page](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/AV1), using **2-pass** encoding:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c:v libaom-av1 -strict -2 -b:v 65k -pass 1 -c:a libfdk_aac -ar 22050 -b:a 22050 -ac 1 -minrate 54k -maxrate 72k -bufsize 33075 -vf scale=-1:360 -movflags +faststart -threads 1 -an -f mp4 /dev/null && _
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c:v libaom-av1 -strict -2 -b:v 65k -pass 2 -c:a libfdk_aac -ar 22050 -b:a 22050 -ac 1 -minrate 54k -maxrate 72k -bufsize 33075 -vf scale=-1:360 -movflags +faststart -threads 1 output.mp4
```

*Note: it may ask you to overwrite /dev/null.*

Thanks to all of you for your help!

Comment: You can add the `-y` global option to the first command if you want to avoid it asking you to overwrite `/dev/null`.

Comment: Thanks @Ilogan for this tip.